# Oracle database table creation

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a user with name **ABC** in Oracle database.
Prior to this i have created a table named **Demo** in user named **SYSTEM**
.Now i need to create a table with same name in **ABC** also.How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prefix tablename with schema (ABC)

```
create table abc.demo (c1 varchar2(10));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch to the Schema like:

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = ABC
```

and then create the table